# EntityFramework 5.0 with CastleWindsor

Tags: entity-framework-5, castle-windsor

As EF 5.0 is already having UnitOfWork pattern implemented so I want to it instead of creating my own IUnitOfWork classes for maintaining transactions. But most of the examples I found on internet are using Separate UnitOfWork instead of EF directly.

I'm trying to implement this using IoC (castle windsor). Could you please provide some samples or direction on implementing this.

Thanks in advance

Sai

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any details about your current Windsor setup or what UoW looks like in EF5 (I don't use it), but based on this [1] it appears they have an IUnitOfWork interface implemented on their db context class.  So this appears to be pretty straightforward to leverage in a dependency injection pattern driven by Windsor.  You'll first want to register the IUnitOfWork interface and implementation with the container.  There's a variety of ways to register components in Windsor.  I prefer installers [2]... so you'll end up with something like this:

```
public class YourInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
   public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   {
      container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<YourDbContext>());
   }
}
```

Then you have this injected into your application's services in some fashion such as:

```
public class YourService
{
    public YourService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
       // rock out
    }
}
```

[1] http://dumians.wordpress.com/2013/04/13/how-to-use-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework/
[2] http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Installers&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: Thanks Kellyb, I have a backend SQL Server, so If I do the container.Register with IUnitOfwork for my dbContext will it work? BTW I will be following Database first approach.